# WebApi is referencing unknown namespace in IIS Express only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

When I try to debug a WebApi project in Visual Studio locally with IIS Express, I suddenly started getting the following error:

```
"ExceptionMessage": "Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. 
This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.
The request has found the following matching controller types:
MyApp.Api.Controllers.ProfileController
MyApp.Web.Controllers.ProfilesController"
```

When I publish the solution to my IIS instance, there is no issue. In the very beginning I did have a MyApp.Web namespace, but that has long since been gone and I can't find any references to it anywhere. MyApp.Api is the correct one.

This just started happening tonight. I tried cleaning & rebuilding with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: It says two profilecontroller, check webapiconfig n ensure u have one api route

Comment: I only have one api route in there and only one ProfileController.cs class

Comment: Go to the output folder and delete any assemblies. It is likely that an old assembly was not removed and led to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Per @LexLi Deleted all files from the /bin folder which still had the .Web dlls hanging around in there. Problem solved.